# How to create the new UIViewController in a Universal Application

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application. I am creating the Universal Application using the Single View Based application model. So, I need to create a new class. But, it gives only a single xib. I need two xibs for iPhone and iPad. Please tell me how to create the two xibs for a single class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new one with same name .. lets suppose your view controller name is "NewViewController" .. your xib will be `NewViewController~ipad` for the iPad and `NewViewController~iPhone` for the iphone .. so when you implement `initWithNibName` just write the basic name for you xib which is `NewViewController` and the iOS will take care about calling the match xib based on current used platform ..  and don't forget to assign the custom class for the file owner in the new xib to be your new class like the image below.

[image]

**For Create new xib check these images :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: That means totally we need to create 2.h files and 2.m files with same name.Am i correct?

Comment: No .. one .h and one .m , and two xib's. read my answer again

Comment: How can i create xib with out .h and .m files.

Comment: New File > User Interface > View.

Comment: press command+n .. then choose user interface under the ios group .. then choose View.

Answer (score 0):

Malek_Jundi has a clear guide on how to create and load .nib file for iphone and ipad.
If you want to create different class for each case (iphone or ipad), you can use IF statement like this:

```
UIViewController *target;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    target = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
} else {
    target = [[NewViewController_ipad alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
}
```

But I am too lazy to input "IF" statement repeatedly in my code to create specific class for iphone/ipad. I have an alternative way:

```
- (Class)idiomClassWithName:(NSString*)className
{
    Class ret;
    NSString *specificName = nil;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        specificName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@_ipad", className];
    } else {
        specificName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@_iphone", className];
    }
    ret = NSClassFromString(specificName);
    if (!ret) {
        ret = NSClassFromString(className);
    }
    return ret;
}

- (void)createSpecificNewController
{
    Class class = [self idiomClassWithName:@"NewViewController"];
    UIViewController *target = [[class alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    //...
}
```